# What is the way to find the size of class and not size of object in CPP using g++ compiler?

Tags: c++

sizeof(className) - gives the size of actually the object since it doesn't include the size of static variable and the Virtual Table which is stored in the static location.

Trying to find out how much memory is occupied by the VTABLE in gcc compiler. As I understand, VTABLE is class property and Vpointer is object property. So, if there are 3 instances of class, there will be 3 virtual pointers. On the other hand, there will be just 1 VTABLE.
Now, when we do sizeof(className) - actually, it gives the size of object rather than sizeof class. I am saying this because it doesn't include the size of VTABLE but includes the size of virtual pointer.
Also, it doesn't include the size of static variable which is a class property and not object property.

```
class A
{
  public:
   virtual void f(){}
   virtual void g() {}
   static int a;
};
```

The size here is 4 bytes because of one virtual pointer.
Sizeof(A) - tells the size of object of A rather than size of class A.

Expectation - To find out the size of class rather than object.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: Classes don't exist after compilation! => Something that does not exist, has no size....

Furthermore the potential existence of a vtable is highly implementation defined and not observable via standard operations… You could of course (rightly) estimate the static size of a vtable and vptr, but that still doesn't buy you much...

Comment: Should you be including the size of the code generated for the member functions in the "size of class"?

Comment: @MFH Objects don't exist after compilation either - there's just memory.

Comment: There is actually no requirement in the standard for a vtable, let alone a means of measuring its size.   A vtable is an implementation choice so the only way - if it exists - to get its size (or, in the case of a class with multiple bases that have virtual functions) sizes will be implementation-specific.

Comment: @immibis That's not quite right (but I guess this depends on your definition of an object) - objects (== collection of bytes with clearly defined layout) exist at runtime.
If that object-definition doesn't suit you, you're right - there is nothing but memory, words and registers after compilation...

Comment: In some cases compilers can optimize out part or all of the vtable